# Can't pass System.out instance properly to FilterOutputStream

Tags: java, stream

Why doesn't this code work, unless I uncomment the `System.out.print(" ");` line?

3 cases:

- `System.out.print(" ");` after `outprint.write(var);` results in: `h e l l o   w o r l`
- `System.out.print(" ");` before `outprint.write(var);` results in: `h e l l o   w o r l d`
- without `System.out.print(" ");` nothing is displayed

To sum up, I do pass the `System.out` instance (which is a `PrintStream`) to the `out` attribute of the `FilterOutputStream` object (which takes an `OutputStream`).

---

```
import java.io.FilterOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CodeCesar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        FilterOutputStream outputstream = new FilterOutputStream(System.out);
        String line = "hello world";
        char[] lst_char = line.toCharArray();

        for (char var : lst_char) {
            try {
                outputstream.write(var);
                System.out.print(" "); <--------- THIS LINE
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to flush the outpustream after you write to it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because you have to manually invoke `outputstream.flush();`  (instead of  `System.out.print()`)

Answer (score 3):

Whatever you added to the stream is being buffered but not being flushed. Without the line try flushing the output-stream.

```
try {
    for (char var : lst_char) {        
        outputstream.write(var);    
    }
    outputstream.flush(); //flush it once you are done writing
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected code for you. use the flush()

```
public class CodeCesar {       
        FilterOutputStream outputstream = new FilterOutputStream(System.out);
        String line = "hello world";
        char[] lst_char = line.toCharArray();
        for (char var : lst_char) {
            try {
                System.out.print(" ");
                outputstream.write(var);
                outputstream.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```